# Webapp from Roo-Script in maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-roo, rapid-prototyping

Assumed this maven-project exists in Subversion:

```
+ myproject
  + src
  | + main
  |   + resources
  |     + script.roo
  + pom.xml
```

This is my pom:

```
<project>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

How to execute the `script.roo` without having `spring-roo` installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is noway to archive this.

Spring Roo is a development tool (like Eclipse) so you need to download and install it to execute roo commands or roo script.